# Android Idea with some special effects

Tags: android

I came up with a little odd idea for the my android application. Simply, my application allows user to enable camera to take a foot live image to figure the foot size, after that, the program will convert foot size to shoe size. I googled with some suggestions like dealing with AI Analyse. 
This is my scratch screenshot

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ofc8vgj1izg32fp/EgBr6KXpYn/AndroidIdea.jpg)

I just wonder whether my idea is possible or not.

Comment: What size (in inches or cm) is a pixel ? If you can come up with a good way of determine that (I would say close to impossible) in a picture taken with you phone cam, your good to go :) You would need to  detect a foot to of course, but that will be the easy part i believe (still really hard through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Yes, of course. It's just a bit of maths and physics. You will have to measure the distance between camera and foot or calibrate your measuring algorithm with e.g. a box of candy of which you know the size of and put it besides your foot.

Without a reference you will never be able to tell the size of an object by the number of pixels it takes on an image.

You'll be better off by just looking at the bottom of your current shoe. If it fits fine, take the same size again, if not, take a slightely larger one. Alternative: Ask your mother, she'll probably know.